# Instantiating SQLAlchemy Classes within a callback function

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlalchemy, tk-toolkit, pysqlite

I am new to SQLAlchemy and Python and am attempting to instantiate an sqlalchemy object within a Tkinter Button callback. Here is the code:

```
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Tests"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    TestName = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, TestName):
       self.TestName = TestName

SaveTestButton = Button(master, text="Save to database", command=saveTest, fg="green",  bg="white", font="Helvetica 10 bold")

NewTestEntry = Entry(master, text="", width = 100)

def saveTest():
    NewTestName = NewTestEntry.get()
    T = Test(NewTestName)
    session.add(T)
    session.commit()
```

Im getting the following error:

```
T = Test("NewTestName")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

It seems to fail to recognize the sqlalchemy "Test" class within the callback. I have tried calling the saveTest function externally from tk to instantiate a Test class and it works. I have also instantiated other classes (not sqlalchemy based) within the callback so it seems really odd that it wouldnt work. There must be a way to do this... Any comments would be much appreciated.
-Daniel W.

Comment: Are you doing `Test=None` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Thank you Brian! I looked it over and found a Test=Listbox in the code that im assuming was overriding the class object in the namespace..? Anyway i updated and it works. Cheers

Comment: I'm guessing the actual code was something like `Test=Listbox(...).grid()` or `Test=Listbox(...).pack()`. Both of those would set Test to None.

Comment: Yes it was the .grid()